# TypeScript: Infer enum value type from enum type

Tags: typescript, generics, enums, type-inference

I wrote a function returning all values of a given enum as array. The implementation works, but I have a problem with the type of the return value.

```
enum Foo {
    FOO_1 = "FOO_1",
    FOO_2 = "FOO_2",
}

function getEnumValues<T>(e:T): T[] {
    let keys: string[] = Object.keys(e);
    keys = keys.filter(key => e[key] !== undefined);
    return keys.map(key => e[key]);
}

const fooValues:Foo[] = getEnumValues(Foo);
```

I get this error:

> Error:(46, 7) TS2322: Type '(typeof Foo)[]' is not assignable to type
>   'Foo[]'.   Type 'typeof Foo' is not assignable to type 'Foo'.

How can I change the signature of `getEnumValues()` in order to return the type `Foo[]` here?

Answer (score 13):

You need to change the definition a bit to infer the type of the enum member, right now `T` will be the enum object itself (aka `typeof T`)

```
enum Foo {
    FOO_1 = "FOO_1",
    FOO_2 = "FOO_2",
}

function getEnumValues<TEnum, TKeys extends string>(e: { [key in TKeys]: TEnum }): TEnum[] {
    let keys = Object.keys(e) as Array<TKeys>;
    keys = keys.filter(key => e[key] !== undefined);
    return keys.map(key => e[key]);
}

const fooValues: Foo[] = getEnumValues(Foo);
```

Note that while this works for enums, it will work for any object it is not restricted to enums

Comment: Apart from being way less specific, you could just change `e:any`, and it would work too.

Comment: @Marco well .. you can type anything as `any` and it will work. The art of using Typescript is never using `any` :P. Also if you use `e:any` you have to also give a type argument to have the corect enum type (ie `getEnumValues<Foo>(Foo)`, like this it is inferred.

Comment: It does work without specifying the concrete type - at least in this case.

Comment: Agreed. I'm just being lazy here.

Answer (score 0):

Personaly I do this:

```
enum Foo {
    FOO_1 = "FOO_1",
    FOO_2 = "FOO_2",
}

const fooValues:Foo[] = Object.values(Foo);
```