# How to reverse typing on a typescript enum?

Tags: typescript, enums

Given an enum in typescript

```js
enum CoffeeSizes {
  Large = 'L',
  Medium = 'M',
  ExtraLarge = 'XL',
}

CoffeeSizes.Large === 'L' // true
```

How do I do the reverse lookup, where I can say

```js
CoffeeSizes.L === 'Large'
```

How can I create a type with the inverse enum?

Comment: Do you want to infer the type from the existing enum, or re-define the enum?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript: Infer enum value type from enum type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50227229/typescript-infer-enum-value-type-from-enum-type)

Comment: @fuzz That link only grab values, I need an inverse enum with type.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48945109/5669456) for a possible reverse mapping implementation. Reverse lookups are not possible for string enums.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse mappings are only possible for numeric non const enums.
As in the example below

```
enum CoffeeSizes {
  Large,
  Medium,
  ExtraLarge
}

const nameOffLargeCoffeeSize = CoffeeSizes[CoffeeSizes.Large];
CoffeeSizes[nameOffLargeCoffeeSize] === CoffeeSizes.Large;
```

You can get more details in [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings)