# Use typescript type in yup schema

Tags: typescript, yup

Can a typescript type be used in a yup validation?

In yup you can:

```
yup.string().oneOf(['salami', 'tuna', 'cheese']);
```

In one of my components I have this type defined:

```
type toppings = 'salami' | 'tuna' | 'cheese';
```

Can I combine these two? I.e.:

```
type toppings = 'salami' | 'tuna' | 'cheese';
yup.string().oneOf(toppings); // <- how?
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `yup.mixed<TYPE>()` passing your generic type.

```
yup.mixed<toppings>().oneOf(['salami', 'tuna', 'cheese']);
```

You are passing it as `yup.string()`, but it isn't a string, it's the type of `'salami' | 'tuna' | 'cheese'`, which contain string but isn't any string, so you need to use `.mixed` to define a specific value.

If you don't want to pass directly the array with the type values, you can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154009/get-array-of-string-literal-type-values) on how to make it.

Comment: Interesting. However, this gives me the error: `'toppingss only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)` on the `.oneOf(toppings)` part.

Comment: @Remi now it's fixed, sorry for that. Please take a look at my edit

Comment: Thanks, no worries. But still I'd have to manually define the values 'salami', 'tuna', 'cheese'. Isn't it possible to get that information from the alias? Since they're already defined there

Comment: @Remi I add how to do that in my answer, just take a look at linked question. You will have to convert the type into a enum and create a function to get the information

Comment: Ah a getEnumValues. Tried that one out and found out the function actually wasn't correct and had some typing issues. Tried this one instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50227229/typescript-infer-enum-value-type-from-enum-type. Do you want me to update your answer with a full example or provide a new one?

Comment: @Remi If you want too, you can, but I think it's better to leave the link to the other question, otherwise my answer will just be a copy of someone else's answer

Answer (score 10):

To build on @Vencovsky's answer a bit, you can use a const assertion if you want to avoid converting the type to an enum.

```js
const possibleToppings = ['salami', 'tuna', 'cheese'] as const;

type toppings = typeof possibleToppings[number]; // 'salami' | 'tuna' | 'cheese'

yup.mixed<toppings>().oneOf([...possibleToppings]);
```